# Are Character and char the same thing?

Tags: java, char, character

I have a map.
 `Map<Character, Integer> map1 = new TreeMap<Character, Integer>();`

I'm using this map to store unique characters I run into while scanning a file. I'm getting a `String` and using `String.toCharArray()` in order to store the characters found in a `char` array.

If I try and put an element from my char array, say `map1.put(charay[I], 1)`, will the map interpret that as it's wrapper class? Or are `character` and `char` different. I was doing some research and it looks like you use wrapper classes when primitive data types wont work (like in map), but will what I'm doing work?

Comment: autoboxing https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: `Character` is the wrapper class of primitive `char`. It provides methods and allows for use in data structures such as maps, lists, etc. They can be used interchangeably with auto-boxing and unboxing.

Comment: That's exactly what I was hoping to hear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Character and char are not the same, the former is a class and the latter a primitive type, although as  you say the class can be considered to provide an object instance "wrapper" representation of the primitive type in places where only objects are allowed and not primitives.

In any place where your code indicates that a conversion from one to the other must occur, rather than giving you a compiler error, instead the java compiler (javac) will insert its own code for you, code that will do the conversion for you.  The conversion is called auto-boxing and auto-unboxing which is equivalent to doing Character.valueOf(char) and Character.charValue().  Additionally, the compiler will do caching of the Character objects produced to limit memory consumption.  Auto-boxing is simply the compiler inserting this conversion and caching code so that your visible code looks cleaner, but in reality that's what is happening, there's just some extra code being inserted by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. [Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) from the the link (note the example),

> *Autoboxing* is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes. For example, converting an `int` to an `Integer`, a `double` to a `Double`, and so on. If the conversion goes the other way, this is called *unboxing*.
>
> Here is the simplest example of autoboxing:
>
> ```
> Character ch = 'a';
> ```